# Can I leave UK on the day my visa expires?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-expiration

I have a valid UK (Visit/Tourist) visa that expires on 30 Jan and my flight is scheduled on the same day morning time is it fine will I have any issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are legally in the UK up to midnight of the expiry date of your visa.  The only problem you might have would come from a delay to your flight (weather, cancelled/missed flight etc) or other unforeseen incident (lost/stolen passport, illness etc) that resulted in you being unable to leave on time. Otherwise, exiting on the last day of your visa’s validity in itself will not cause any issues.