# Can I visit uk 5 days before my visa expires?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-free-entry, entry-permit

I'm planning to visit UK on 25th January but my visa will expire in 30 January

Is it OK to make a journey in the last few days of my visa?

Comment: Both your questions have been answered in your previous question here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151799/can-i-leave-uk-on-the-day-my-visa-expires

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I leave UK on the day my visa expires?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151799/can-i-leave-uk-on-the-day-my-visa-expires)

Comment: For clarity, what type of visa and have you used it previously? What’s your citizenship? You’ve tagged your question with ‘visa-free-entry’, ‘visas’, and ‘entry-permit’ so it’s not clear on what basis you plan to enter.